# Update только нужных полей

Tags: orm, linq2sql

Есть класс Product:

```
public class Product
{
    piblic int id {get;set;}
    public int? article {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}
```

Есть объект класса Product:

```
Product product = new Product 
{
    id = 1,
    name = "phone"
}
```

Так как поле article мы не инициализировали, то оно равно null

Теперь с помощью Linq2Db я хочу сохранить этот объект в БД, либо обновить его, если он уже существует:

```
using var db = new DBContext();

            try
            {
                db.Insert(product );
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string errMessage = e.Message;
                if (e.HResult == -2147467259)
                {
                    Update<Product>(product);

                }
            }
```

Здесь я пытаюсь вставить в базу product, но если таковой уже существует, отлавливаю исключение и обновляю этот объект в БД. Все бы хорошо, но после обновления свойству article, сохраненному в базе присваивается null.

В связи с этим вопрос: как сделать update так, чтобы обновилось только поле name, а поле article осталось не измененным?

Answer (score 0):

Вот, нашел как:

```
using var db = new DBContext();

try
{
    db.GetTable< Product>().InsertOrUpdate(() => new Product{ id = product.id, },
                    t => new Product{name = product.name });
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Если кто знает что получше, напишите.